# Can I compute the mean of two different axes of a 4D array using np.mean?

Tags: python-3.x

The data from my files is stored in 4D arrays in python of shape (64,128,64,3). The code I run is in a grid code format, so the shape tells us that there are 64 cells in the x,128 in the y, and 64 in the z. The 3 is the x, y, and z components of velocity. What I want to do is compute the average x velocity in each direction for every cell in y.

Let's start in the corner of my grid. I want the first element of my average array to be the average of the x velocity of all the x cells and all the z cells in position y[0]. The next element should be the same, but for y[1]. The end result should be an array of shape (128).

I'm fairly new to python, so I could be missing something simple, but I don't see a way to do this with one np.mean statement because you need to sum over two axes (In this case, 1 and 2 I think). I tried

```
velx_avg = np.mean(ds['u'][:,:,:,0],axis=1)
```

here, ds is the data set I've loaded in, and the module I've used to load it stores the velocity data under 'u'. This gave me an array of shape (64,64).

What is the most efficient way to produce the result that I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `flatten` command to make your life here much easier, this takes an `np.ndarray` and flattens it into one dimension.

The challenge here is trying to find your definition of 'efficient', but you can play around with that yourself. To do what you want, I simply iterate over the array and flatten the x and z component into a continuous array, and then take the mean of that, see below:

```py
velx_avg = np.mean([ds['u'][:, i, :, 0].flatten() for i in range(128)], axis=1)
```